# compare two column that in relation

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2, I need compare two column that in relation.

For example be like:

```
$query->andWhere(['product.form' => 'subcategory.form']);
```

build this query:

```
WHERE `product`.`form`='subcategory.form'
```

But I need be like this query:

```
WHERE `product`.`form`=`subcategory`.`form`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, It's easy with this code:

```
$query->andWhere('`product`.`form`=`subcategory`.`form`');
```